# Difference between ので and て Form?

Tags: grammar, て-form

I've found this question across my JLPT N4 practice

> 1) 楽しかったですよ。参加（できなくて/できないので）、残念でしたね.

The answer is できなくて
What are the differences between ので and て in usage for reasonings?

Comment: But it doesn't look like a test on the difference between the two forms, but rather on tense agreement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The の simply adds an explanatory tone to the sentence.

> 今忙しいので、どうぞお先に行ってください。 (As I am) busy right now, please go on ahead.

But I think you're veering away from the original grammatical matter being tested in your practice sentence. macraf is giving you a good hint.